# TSQL "BULK INSERT" from a Macbook

Tags: sql-server, macos, t-sql, azure, bulkinsert

These are the objects involved:

- My Macbook
- SQL Server hosted in Azure
- SQL Server client: `DbVisualizer` or `macsqlclient` (like Window's Management Studio)
- a file in my Mac located in `\Users\john\persons.csv`

I'm trying to do a TSQL BULK INSERT using my sql client, like this:

```
BULK INSERT persons from '\users\john\persons.csv'
WITH 
  (
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
  );
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
 Cannot bulk load because the file "\users\john\persons.csv" could not be opened.
 Operating system error code (null).
```

...How can I solve this? what file path should I use in a Macbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have  a storage account in Azure to use Bulk Insert..below are the steps

**Step1:**

> CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
>    WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
>           LOCATION = 'https://myazureblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net',
>           CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential);

**Step2:**
now you need to place your file in blob container   and access it like below

```
BULK INSERT Product
FROM 'product.csv'
WITH (  DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
        FORMAT='CSV', CODEPAGE = 65001, --UTF-8 encoding
        FIRSTROW=2,
        TABLOCK);
```

Credentials are not required,if your blob is public,else you need to create credentials

```
- CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'some strong password';

-- 1.1.2. (optional) Create credential with Azure Blob SAS
--
-- CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential 
-- WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
-- SECRET = 'sv=2015-12-11&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwac&se=2017-02-01T00:55:34Z&st=2016-12-29T16:55:34Z&spr=https&sig=copyFromAzurePortal';
-- NOTE: DO NOT PUT FIRST CHARACTER '?'' IN SECRET!!!
```

**References:**
 [sql-server-samples/samples/features/sql-bulk-load/load-from-azure-blob-storage/LoadFromAzureBlobStorage.sql](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/sql-bulk-load/load-from-azure-blob-storage/LoadFromAzureBlobStorage.sql)

Comment: hmmm... where should I paste the code from step 1? clearly not in my DbVisualizer nor macsqlclient. Should I paste it in azure's terminal?

Comment: No,i assume you are running the bulk insert from some kind of editor,, you can use editor available in azure portal

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/t-sql-query-editor-in-browser-azure-portal/

Comment: It worked fine. `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` is a TSQL command